# Visualizing Audio File Waveform, Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, signal-processing, web-audio-api

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to visualize the waveform of a audio file (.mp3, .wav) using canvas. Actually, pretty clueless on how to achieve this.

I'm using the Web Audio API. I've been playing around with the code on here to achieve my goal: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Visualizations_with_Web_Audio_API#Creating_a_waveformoscilloscope. Unfortunately, I'm running into problems. Examples below

How the wave form looks with canvas:

[image: Image of waveform]

How the waveform of the song should look. (this is from Ableton)
[image]

If it matters, the audio buffer size for this song in particular is 8832992.

The Audio Buffer(songAudioBuffer) of this song looks like:

```
AudioBuffer {

​    duration: 184.02066666666667,
​    length: 8832992,
​    numberOfChannels: 2,
    sampleRate: 48000

}
```

Current program flow: User selects a file from their computer -> User clicks on load -> FileReader reads the audio file and turns it into an ArrayBuffer -> Take ArrayBuffer and create an AudioBuffer

```
const audioFile = document.querySelector('.audioFile') // Input element where user loads the audio file to
const load = document.querySelector('.load') // button element
load.addEventListener('click', () => {

    const fileReader = new FileReader();


    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(audioFile.files[0]);
    fileReader.onload = function(evt){

        audioContext = new AudioContext(); // global var

        audioBuffer = audioContext.decodeAudioData(fileReader.result); // global var

        // Type of AudioBuffer
        audioBuffer.then((res) => {

            songAudioBuffer = res; // songAudioBuffer is a global var
            draw()

        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        })
    }
})


function draw(){

    const canvas = document.querySelector('.can'); // canvas element
    const canvasCtx = canvas.getContext('2d');



    canvas.style.width = WIDTH + 'px';
    canvas.style.height = HEIGHT + 'px';

    canvasCtx.fillStyle = 'rgb(260, 200, 200)';
    canvasCtx.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    canvasCtx.lineWidth = 2;
    canvasCtx.strokeStyle = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)';
    canvasCtx.beginPath();


    const analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser();
    analyser.fftSize = 2048;

    const bufferLength = songAudioBuffer.getChannelData(0).length;
    var dataArray = new Float32Array(songAudioBuffer.getChannelData(0));
    analyser.getFloatTimeDomainData(songAudioBuffer.getChannelData(0));


    var sliceWidth = WIDTH / bufferLength;
    var x = 0;


    for(var i = 0; i < bufferLength; i++) {

        var v = dataArray[i] * 2;
        var y = v + (HEIGHT / 4); // Dividing height by 4 places the waveform in the center of the canvas for some reason

        if(i === 0) canvasCtx.moveTo(x, y);
        else {
            canvasCtx.lineTo(x, y);
        }

        x += sliceWidth;
    }


    canvasCtx.lineTo(canvas.width, canvas.height / 2);
    canvasCtx.stroke();
}
```

Comment: Where are `canvas` and `canvasCtx` declared?

Comment: They're global variables. Sorry, it's a bit messy! I've been playing around with the code just to get something up and running fast

Comment: What's `songAudioBuffer`?

Comment: @zer00ne Updated post

Comment: In their code, they have; “var v = dataArray[i] / 128.0;” you multiply yours by 2. What’s the difference?

Comment: @user2072826 I'm not entirely sure. it's one of those things that I'm completely lost on. I recently saw that 128 could be in reference to the amount of samples. I'm not sure what dividing the elements by the amount of samples mean, but in my head, I figure multiplying by 2 would make the amplitude of the waves a bit larger (not the case)

Comment: Maybe this page that allows to select a file and draws a waveform will be useful: https://jakearchibald.github.io/aac-decode-bug/

Comment: This library: https://github.com/bbc/waveform-data.js

Comment: Have you tried using wavesurfer.js ? It's a customizable audio waveform visualization, built on top of Web Audio API and HTML5 Canvas. 
Link : https://wavesurfer-js.org/

Answer (score 0):

Just take a few steps back, fill an array with 5 values between -1 and 1 and see if you can draw that. Makes it way easier to see what is going wrong.